# How to efficiently version a group of related rows in a database

Tags: java, database, oracle, version-control

I have a scenario in which i have to write a versioning logic for a logical group of items in a database. It can be compared like trying to maintain versions a folder containing some files. Below is the table containing items of a group by ID 1000.  **I have to perform the versioning at the group level so that i am able to go back to a particular state in which the group was at some point in the past**.

```
DB Optn   | ITEM_ID     GROUP_ID   ITEM_NAME           TEXT              CREATED_DATE
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Insert(1) |   1        1000       Note 1           <p>Now</p>            22-Feb-18  
Insert(2) |   2        1000       Note 2           <p>Next</p>           22-Feb-18      
Update(3) |   2        1000       Note 2 update    <p>Nowe Update</p>    22-Feb-18
Insert(4) |   3        1000       Note 3           <p>New Next</p>       22-Feb-18
```

I have to maintain the versions of all these rows as a group. For this purpose i have created a shadow table of the above table like this :

```
DB Opt    | ITEM_ID     GROUP_ID   ITEM_NAME        TEXT         CREATED_DATE  VERSION
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Insert(1) |   1        1000       Note 1        <p>Now</p>         22-Feb-18     1
          |
Insert(1) |   1        1000       Note 1        <p>Now</p>         22-Feb-18     2
Insert(2) |   2        1000       Note 2        <p>Next</p>        22-Feb-18     2
          |
Insert(1) |   1        1000       Note 1        <p>Now</p>         22-Feb-18     3
Update(3) |   2        1000       Note 2 update <p>Nowe Update</p> 22-Feb-18     3
          |
Insert(1) |   1        1000       Note 1        <p>Now</p>         22-Feb-18     4
Update(3) |   2        1000       Note 2 update <p>Nowe Update</p> 22-Feb-18     4
Insert(4) |   3        1000       New Insert    <p>New Next</p>    22-Feb-18     4
```

This is my current approach. In this case i am able to keep track of every item that is added/update to the group id 1000. So when i want to go back to a particular version, i have the state of the items in the group readily available to for that version.

Is this an efficient approach? The pain point i see here is that even for a update of an single item in group, **i have to replicate all the other non updated rows to create a new version**. This will give some problem if let's say i have 10 items for group id 1000 and i update Item 3. In that case a new version will be created with all 9 non-updated rows  and 1 updated row again.

Can i modify my shadow table structure so that there will not be a need to duplicate theun-edited items but still will be ale to maintain and go back to the state in which the group was at a particular time? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: If you are using hibernate or JPA, you can use hibernate envers. It's easy to configure it and requires almost no changes to the business logic. You will need to create an audit table(you can configure it to create them automatically for you as well) for each entity you want to audit. Check the below links: *1.* http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/             
              *2.* https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-envers-getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

It does look like as your groups get larger and the number of edits pile up then the approach will become more expensive.

A possible alternative might involve taking an 'audit table' approach:

1). Add a separate unique identity column to the Items table and create a Group-Version table that looks like this:

```
GROUP_ID    VERSION    ITEM_ID
```

2). When you insert into or update the Items table, you can add / remove the old & new Item IDs from the group for that version in the Group-Version table.

Comment: Let me check this approach.. will get back to you shortly..Thanks

Comment: I think this will work for 2 version, current and old.. In my requirement i need to track many (<=10) versions. In that case, i think the no. of inserts (db read/write) will be the same in this approach